# connect to device using MAC address with java

Tags: java, static-ip-address

I have a device in my local network with unknown IP address and outside of my sub-net (it was configured previously as static IP in another network). I know though its MAC address. Is it possible with java to communicate with that device using only its MAC address?

Comment: Define "subnet". If not on the same physical net then no chance. And even if it were, this would mean doing an ARP query which you can't do in Java.

Comment: It is in the same physical network but with a static IP configured previously in another network, so it is within a different range as mine.

Comment: Do you have to use a specific protocol or you can write the protocoll?

Comment: I can write it. The final goal here is to find a way to re-configure the device and assign it a new IP address. But first I need to know if there's a way to connect. Thanks.

Comment: With pure Java you cannot. Do you know what a routing table is?

Comment: yes. is there a way to specify a route having only the mac address?